# Why isn't agent() set when using LWP::Parallel::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent

It appears to be undefined when looking at `UserAgent.pm`. At least, as far as I know, it is undefined when the routine gets to that part, even though I'm explicitly setting it with `$pua->agent()`. Is this a bug? There's also `init_header()`, but when I tried `$pua->request->init_header()`, it also failed to set.

```
#!/bin/perl

use LWP::Parallel::UserAgent;

my $ua_string =
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36";

my $url  = "http://www.example1.com";
my $url2 = "http://www.example2.com";

my $reqs = [
    HTTP::Request->new( 'GET', $url ),
    HTTP::Request->new( 'GET', $url2 )
];

my ( $req, $res );

my $pua = LWP::Parallel::UserAgent->new();

$pua->agent($ua_string);

foreach $req ( @$reqs ) {
    $pua->register( $req );
}

my $entries = $pua->wait();
foreach ( keys %$entries ) {
    $res = $entries->{$_}->response;
    my $r = $res;
    my @redirects;
    while ( $r ) {
        $res = $r;
        $r   = $r->previous;
        push( @redirects, $res ) if $r;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code works fine. Could you post the error message you're receiving? Also what versions of LWP and LWP::Parallel::UserAgent you're using.

Comment: Latest version. It doesn't set the User-Agent string for me. It runs fine, but doesn't set the value.

Comment: If you stick a `print "The user-agent is: ".$pua->agent` right after you set it you get what?

Comment: I'm looking at my log files. It isn't in my log file. If I go in and manually edit the perl module UserAgent.pm and set the agent variable there, it works, and shows up in my log. But not when using $pua->agent().

Comment: When you say "it isn't in my log file" do you mean you get `The user-agent is: ` or you just get nothing? If you get nothing then that line is simply never being run. Again, because you're not using `strict` nor `warnings` I suspect what's really going on is you have a typo and you're passing `undef` in. Try printing `$ua_string`. Also turn on strict and warnings. Or you're using someone's hacked version of LWP::UserAgent (since you're editing the module very likely). Try diffing it against a fresh download.

Comment: The installed version is not hacked or modified. I added strict, and no errors or warnings on the code I posted. It is not being set in my apache log.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about the confusion, `$pua->agent` is set, but LWP::Parallel::UserAgent isn't using it. This is [a long standing bug in LWP::Parallel::UserAgent](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=84894).

LWP::Parallel::UserAgent is a subclass of LWP::UserAgent but it's a poorly behaved subclass. Rather than using accessors it grabs at internal fields and assumes the agent will be stored in `$self->{agent}`. Maybe it once was, but it isn't anymore.

Your particular problem is in [`LWP::Parallel::UserAgent::init_request()` starting at line 1506](https://metacpan.org/source/MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62/lib/LWP/Parallel/UserAgent.pm#L1506).

```
# Extract fields that will be used below
my ($agent, $from, $timeout, $cookie_jar,
    $use_eval, $parse_head, $max_size, $nonblock) =
  @{$self}{qw(agent from timeout cookie_jar
              use_eval parse_head max_size nonblock)};
```

This assumes the user-agent is stored in `$self->{agent}`. It isn't. It should instead do something like this to call each accessor in turn.

```
my %fields;
my @fields = qw(agent from timeout cookie_jar parse_head max_size);
for my $field (@fields) {
    $fields{$field} = $self->$field();
}
```

Or just use the accessors directly. This will use the documented interface for LWP.

`nonblock` and `use_eval` are special cases. These are not LWP::UserAgent fields, they were added by LWP::Parallel. There is no accessor method for `use_eval`. There is a `LWP::Parallel::UserAgent::nonblock()` but its only a setter. I don't think this is intentional.

Since it doesn't define an accessor for `use_eval`, and should add one. And you could fix `nonblock` to always return its value.

```
sub nonblock {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{'nonblock'} = $_[0] if defined $_[0];
    return $self->{nonblock};
}
```

LWP::Parallel::UserAgent is being actively maintained, [you should send a bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=ParallelUserAgent) and maybe a patch.

Comment: I get libwww-perl/6.13 when I add the line. It should also show up in my apache logs. It does not, it is just a "-". I have installed LWP::Parallel::UserAgent from source, it is not modified. It will not pick up the the agent() string.

Comment: I installed libwww-perl-6.15 and ParallelUserAgent-2.62 from the source, and there is no change. $pua->agent() is not sent when a connection is made. It is set in the program, but not sent at connection time.

Comment: You're not showing us the real code, you probably have a typo. Turn on strict and warnings, fix all the problems, then see what happens.

Comment: That's the entire program. I am running exactly what I posted.

Comment: @LukasNelson Note that the Perl you run on the command line and the Perl that runs in Apache, especially if it's mod_perl, are not necessarily the same thing. If they are, they're not necessarily seeing the same modules. Try `print $INC{"LWP/Parallel/UserAgent.pm"}` and `print $INC{"LWP/UserAgent.pm"}` and see what you're actually loading.

Comment: I am running command line perl, not apache mod-perl, that is not installed. I have strict, warnings set. There are none with the code I posted. That code does NOT send the User-Agent string while making a connection to ANY web server. I tried two different hosts. The code runs perfectly fine without any errors, so I am wondering if the problem is with the module itself.

Comment: @LukasNelson I have those same versions and it works fine. It's something on your end.

Comment: Its not on my end. The $agent variable in the module UserAgent.pm is not defined. If I add a value, the same value as in my program, then it works. Somewhere there is a break in communication.

Comment: @LukasNelson If `$agent` is not defined in `LWP::UserAgent::new()` (ie. you didn't pass it in) it uses `$class->_agent` which is `sub _agent       { "libwww-perl/$LWP::VERSION" }`. See line 112. `$self->agent(defined($agent) ? $agent : $class->_agent) if defined($agent) || !$def_headers || !$def_headers->header("User-Agent");`

Comment: I'm using LWP::Parallel::UserAgent::new(), not LWP::UserAgent::new().

Comment: @LukasNelson LWP::Parallel::UserAgent is a subclass of LWP::UserAgent, though it takes some liberties. Did you ever try `print $pua->agent`?

Comment: And if its not defined, it should use the default, which would be libwww-perl-6.15 as the User-Agent, or whatever version is installed. However, not even the default is being defined. Somewhere, something is broken. I don't think its the code, I think its the module. That, or I'm not setting it properly. And If I'm not setting it properly, the alternative is to set your own headers. That said, wouldn't $pua->request->init_header('New-Header: New Header') work?

Comment: @LukasNelson  Did you ever try `print $pua->agent`? I'm guessing that works but the header isn't actually getting set. Right?

Comment: Yes, it prints the version if its not defined from the program. I removed the line completely, so that $pua->agent() is not being set. It should then use the default. This does not happen either. The default should show libwww-perl-6.15 in my log file, but it shows a "-".

Comment: @LukasNelson I found the problem. It's a bug in LWP::Parallel::UserAgent.

Comment: I thought it might have been a bug.

Comment: Thanks for finding the root cause. It appears that someone did submit a bug report 2 years ago. Since it has gone unresolved, I imagine its on a TODO list of low priority.

Comment: @LukasNelson I think providing the root cause would make it much easier for the author to patch it.

Comment: At the start of the file, there is a Parallel::UserAgent entry
my %fields = ( ... ). I added agent there. That should fix $pua->agent(). Right? However, it needs to be pulled and assigned somewhere. So I added sub agent {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{'agent'} = $_[0] if defined $_[0];
    return $self->{agent};
}. And it works. HOORAY!!!!!!!

Comment: @LukasNelson  That `%fields` you found controls automatic generation of accessors. It might "work", but I'm afraid you're overriding the existing `LWP::UserAgent::agent()` accessor and where it stores its data. That will probably lead to other subtle bugs. The real fix is to change LWP::Parallel::UserAgent to not make assumptions about the internals of the LWP::UserAgent object.